# jQuery getJSON odd parse error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have this simple JSON file, containing paths to folders and image files inside of it:

```
{ "foldery" : [
    {
      "foName": "website/img/post1",
      "files" : [
        "website/img/post1/a.jpeg",
        "website/img/post1/b.jpg",
        "website/img/post1/c.jpeg",
        "website/img/post1/d.jpg",
        "website/img/post1/e.jpeg",
        "website/img/post1/f.jpg",
        "website/img/post1/g.jpg",
        "website/img/post1/h.jpg"
      ]
    },
    {
      "foName": "website/img/postdrugi",
      "files" : [
        "website/img/postdrugi/20150530_111106.jpg",
        "website/img/postdrugi/20150530_113842.jpg",
        "website/img/postdrugi/20150530_131251.jpg",
        "website/img/postdrugi/20151022_165146.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And a small getJSON function fired on a click of an element:

```
function getImages(dir){

  function select(o) {

    var length = o.foldery.length;
    //getting the length, and firing a for for all of it's elements
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (o.foldery[i].foName == dir) {
          // if the foName is the same as the functions argument, place 'files' of it into array
            return o.foldery[i].files;
        }
    }
}

 $.getJSON("nameindex.json", function(o) {
   console.log("getJSON success");
   var result = select(o);
   var $thmb = $(".thmb .sec");
   var thumbLength = 0;
   $thmb.children().remove();
   for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
           $thmb.append('<div class="img"><img src="'+result[i]+'" alt=""/></div>');
   }

    }).fail( function(d, textStatus, error) {
        console.error("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: " + error);
    });
}
```

Now, one day ago the function worked fine on my laptop. Today I moved all the files to and identical settings WAMP on a different PC, ran the code on chrome (same as worked before)....and nothing happens. The 'failed' function returns me this:

> getJSON failed, status: parsererror, error: SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token ]

Which is weird because the JSON file (if my linter isn't lying to me) is written properly.
On the page I've witnessed the error jQuery is placed at the beginning of `<body>` tags, but I've been getting the same issue everywhere else.
All the other jQuery elements on the webpage work just fine.

Has anyone else witnessed this problem and possibly knows a workaround?
Also it would be nice to provide a small explanation on why is this error happening.

**EDIT: Okay so this now works. It started to work by itself**
Still not deleting or posting an answer to this question, because I'm truly curious what was wrong with it before.

Small update: The code seems highly unstable even on the same machine. For instance. Sometimes it works for file1.json and doesn't work for file2.json even if file2 is a direct copy of file1.

Comment: What are you using to generate the JSON on the server side? Because if you use a proper JSON serializer (as opposed to string concatenation) then this error should not be possible.

Comment: Also - wouldn't it make more sense to do the filtering for `dir` on the server side instead of sending all that JSON to the client and then throw away most of it immediately?

Comment: @Tomalak the presented syntax was hand written

Comment: @Tomalak filtering on a server side wouldn't do the trick, because the function the json is made for should print out dynamically all the image files from a specified folder, when I click on the said folder

Comment: I was just thinking aloud. I would fetch the data that belongs to a folder if and when the user clicks on it. That's probably preferable to fetching it all and then never using most of it because the user never clicks on most of the folders.

Comment: So you say a better option would be to have a separate json file in every folder, containing the data?

Comment: I thought that some server side script would create the data and return it as JSON. I did not think you would have physical JSON files flying around. As I said, I'm just giving you things to think about, you can do whatever works best for you.